# TCP/IP Server-Client Are there data sending limits?

Tags: python, swift, sockets, tcp

I am writing numbers between 100-255 to control the speed of my gearmotor. (under 100 it has trouble running).

On my UDOO I am running the TCP/IP Server code written in python. It binds the server address and and then listens and accepts the connection from client.
It executes a while loop which receives data from the TCP/IP Client (my iPhone) and then prints it and writes it (serially) to the Arduino chip on my UDOO.
**EDIT: Here is the full Python server code**

```
import socket
import sys
import serial

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('IP', 10000)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection...'
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address
while True:
    data = connection.recv(16)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
    ser.write(data)
```

The swift code on my iPhone is using this command to connect to the same IP
that the python code is connecting to.

NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName()

The accelerometer data is written to the output stream using

outputStream.write(string, maxLength: count(string))

If I angle my iPhone towards the right, the speed of the gearmotor will increase.

While accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1 the speed of the gearmotor changes with a 1 second delay. The python server code is receiving 1 packet per second and there no transmission errors. The numbers that show up are between 100 and 255.

If I set the update interval of the accelerometer to 0.01 the python code receives 100 packets per second. An example of the numbers that show up are as follows:

```
received "198"
received "184"
received "179"
received "196"
received "204"
received "2061991871851851"
received "8217717417718118"
received "5185176169184187"
received "1811401761961901"
received "6213912912712612"
received "2118115114105"
received "1051051001001001"
received "0010010110110110"
received "1101101101101101"
received "1011011011011011"
received "0110110110110110"
received "1101101101101101"
received "1011011011011011"
received "0110110110110110"
received "1"
received "1011011011011011"
received "0110110110110110"
received "1101101101101101"
received "101101"
received "101"
received "101"
received "101"
```

The numbers like 198, 184, 179 are accurate and are correctly transmitted because that is the angle I am holding my iPhone. The other numbers greater than 3 digits or over 255 are not supposed to show up and the swift code is not programmed to create them, there must be a problem with the TCP/IP transmission when it receives 100 packets per second.

When the update interval is 0.1 there is still some problems but less frequent.

Comment: It could be the output cannot keep up and it's appending values onto the same line.

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> The numbers like 198, 184, 179 are accurate and are correctly
>   transmitted because that is the angle I am holding my iPhone. The
>   other numbers greater than 3 digits or over 255 are not supposed to
>   show up and the swift code is not programmed to create them, there
>   must be a problem with the TCP/IP transmission when it receives 100
>   packets per second.

Perhaps the numbers do make sense, after all. I just added spaces to make the point:

```
received "206 199 187 185 185 1"
received "82 177 174 177 181 18"
received "5 185 176 169 184 187"
received "181 140 176 196 190 1"
```

Comment: I also recognized this fact. When I was sending the number '101' it got pushed all onto one line. I believe these long strings of numbers is whats making my motor behave erratically. The numbers are all getting pushed into being sent at the same time and I want to fix that to make my motor run smoothly.